# How to record or get the audio while the audio is playing in windows phone 8?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, audio

noob here.

I am developing an app for windows phone that streams audio from the web. I've put the play function with MediaElement class, and i have no problem with it.

Then, i want to add a feature to get/record the audio that i stream. I've googling and didn't find what i want.

Is there a way to do that?

Regards, 
BM

Answer (score 0):

This is the Microphone class link which can be used to capture audi.

Give a try and let me know

[Microphone to capture audio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.audio.microphone%28v=xnagamestudio.42%29.aspx)

also go nthrough this link

[capturing and playing audio](http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/Recording-And-Playing-Recorded-Audio-in-Windows-Phone-7-2211.php)